# CSS selector performance - pseudo selectors

Tags: performance, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

CSS Selectors are parsed right to left, and then displayed.

With this in mind, based on this code:

```
<a href="#" class="myImage">
    <img>
</a>
```

Which is more performant?:

```
.myImage img
```

or

```
.myImage img:only-child
```

Does `:only-child` help specificity in selector selection? So instead of initially matching all `<img>` in the document then looking for the parent class, does it only match `<img>`'s that are the only child (thereby reducing the pool of selections)?

reference read: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

**EDIT**

Found further reading:

> The sad truth about CSS3 selectors is that they really shouldn’t be
>   used at all if you care about page performance. Decorating your markup
>   with classes and ids and matching purely on those while avoiding all
>   uses of sibling, descendant and child selectors will actually make a
>   page perform significantly better in all browsers.

-David Hyatt (architect for Safari and WebKit, also worked on Mozilla, Camino, and Firefox)
Source: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

Comment: You are doing two different things with those selectors. You would have to try to achieve something relative to make a comparison in the first place. I'd believe if you are trying to apply a style on the only child of your img, then obviously it would be the better option, since img will apply the style to all img in the .myImg class, which is something you don't want.

Comment: "Does :only-child help specificity in selector selection?" Well, yes... that's the whole point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, so this depends completely on the use case. What I'm going to do is handle cases.

### Point 1 - Concerning given example

---

**Case A**

Say your code is simply:

```
<a href="#" class="myImage">
    <img>
</a>
```

In this case `.myImage img` and `.myImage img:only-child` will have essentially identical performance hits. Reason being is as follows:

CSS performance hits are derived from having to style or re-style boxes. What CSS does is affect your graphics processor, not the CPU, so we only care about visual updates. And styling things again with duplicate properties DOES cause a redraw (By this I mean duplicate properties that are applied at a later time, which selectors generally cause).

Usually, `.myImage img` would style ALL `<img>`s in `.myImage`. While using the `only-child` selector may not style all (obviously).

*But in this example, both `.myImage img` and `.myImage img:only-child` would do identical things, since they would both cause 1 draw/redraw on the same box.*

---

**Case B**

But suppose we have:

```
<a href="#" class="myImage">
    <img>
    <img>
</a>
```

Here though, we have a different story.

*In this example, `only-child` wouldn't work at all, since `<img>` is not the only child.*

---

**Case C**

Finally, suppose you have this, but you only want to style the  under the :

```
<a href="#" class="myImage">
    <img>
</a>
<div class="myImage>
    <img>
    <img>
</div>
```

*In this case, using the `only-child` selector would be significantly better performance-wise, since you only will style one element, instead of three.*

---

### Conclusion and Takeaway

Basically, remember a few things.

- CSS selectors help you with writing code because you get to add less IDs and Classes, however, they are almost always less efficient than using all IDs and Classes, because using selectors will causes extra redraws. (Since you'll inevitably style multiple elements with some selector, and then re-style other things with IDs or classes, causing unnecessary redraws)
- `only-child` is NOT faster than `.class child` if that .class only has one child.
- Technically what you are comparing are two completely different things, used for different purposes.

**Conclusion**

In final answer to your question. In your shown example, neither is more efficient than the other since they cause identical redraws.

However, as

> "Does `:only-child` help specificity in selector selection?"

goes: Yes, that's the point of the selector. See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_only-child.asp

*Sources:*
I am a significant volunteer developer for Mozilla Thunderbird and the Mozilla project and work in the CSS area.

**FYI**

There are of course weird exceptions to this, but I won't go over them here since I think your exact question doesn't give a brilliant example.

### Point 2 - Concerning speed of find selectors

I am purposely trying to drive home the point that it is the drawing the causes the CSS perf hit, not finding the selectors. **However**, the reason I say this is not because finding selectors takes no time, but instead because it's time is miniscule to the time caused by drawing. That said, if you did have 5,000 `<div>`s or something, and attempted to style a few using pseudo selectors, it would definitely a little longer than using CSS classes and IDs.

Again though, in your example it would make no difference, since it would look through each element anyway. Why `only-child` is helpful perf-wise is because it would stop searching for some element after it finds more than one child, whereas simply doing `class child` would not.

The problem with pseudo selectors is that they usually require a lot of extra searching AND it happens after IDs, classes, and such.

The links you provided are actually very helpful and I'm surprised they didn't answer your question.

One thing I should point out is that many selectors believed to be slow may be vastly improved now. See: http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/css-selector-performance-has-changed-for-the-better/

Remember selector performance is only important on very large websites.

Comment: "And styling things again with duplicate properties DOES cause a redraw." Are you referring to two rules affecting the same element? If so, surely per-element cascade resolution would prevent that? Or am I being naïve?

Comment: @BoltClock: No, that is correct. I should have been more specific. My understanding is that per-element cascading only applies to normal CSS rules. However, changes via JS will cause a redraw, similar techniques may face the same issue. The real thing I was pointing out is that CSS performance is almost completely dependent on how much it has to draw, not how fast it can find elements.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. The links did essentially answer my question, however I left it open for discussion.

Comment: @Josiah: Ah, I see what you mean.